# Prevent windows 10 from saving zip password

Tags: windows-10, zip, credentials

It seems that windows 10 saves the password of zip folders during your login session. Once you enter your zip password once, you can access the file as many times as you want during one login session. If I want to manually remove the stored login session, all I have to do is go to my user account -> manage credentials -> and remove the stored password.

But how can I prevent windows from saving the password in the first place ?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on my Windows 10 box with WinZip and WinRAR

Comment: I'm talking about the native shell "compressed folder" interface

Comment: You cannot password protect those archives, that has never been a feature, of send to archive.

Comment: If you password protect them with a 3rd-party software, but then use the windows explorer to open them, windows will remember the password till you logoff

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to remove those passwords without having to get into control panel every time.  Use this command in a batch file.

FOR /f "tokens=2-3 delims==" %%G IN ('cmdkey /list ^| find ".zip"') DO cmdkey /delete:"%%G=%%H"

Comment: It's not a bad idea to use cmdkey. I didn't know that you can manipulate the list of credentials using that command. Though it doesn't answer my question, but it's interesting to know that :) kudos